# Different from from before

Tags: word-usage

If we wanted to avoid "different than" in "different than from before", we would end up with "different from from before", which is clearly non idiomatic.

Yet, I don't think "different from from before" and "different from before" are interchangeable: the former seems short for "different from the one from before", whereas the latter "different from the way he/she/it was before".

How would you rewrite "different than from before" if you wanted to avoid "different than"?

Comment: If _from before_ is perceived as a time expression, like _the before time_ is, then _different from [from before]_ makes sense. Otherwise, _different from before_ is the normal way of notating _different_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Do you see any difference in meaning between "The situation is different from before" and "The situation is different than from before"?

Comment: Well, _different than_ is not recommended. _Than_ is normally limited to comparative constructions. So I would use the first and not the second, though I would wonder whether the speaker of the second thought there was a special meaning attached. People often do.

Comment: I'm suggesting that the two sentences have different meanings when no further context is provided: "The situation is different from [what it was] before" and "The situation is different from [the one] from before".

Comment: If you pronounced it correctly, so that the listener could distinguish the constituents, yes. However, as a written sentence, it's ungrammatical, and therefore has no meaning; certainly not a separate meaning from the other one.

Comment: So you would simply replace "different than from before" with "different from before". By the way, "different than" should be acceptable in "A is more different than B from C".

Comment: Well, yes, but that's because _different than_ isn't a constituent in _A is more different than B from C_. The _than_ in that sentence goes with the comparative _more_.

Comment: I know: it's all about parsing. Anyway, "different than" is acceptable when followed by a full clause according to the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=different), which relies on a "Usage Panel" of experts. But my original question is not about "than vs from".

Comment: _Than_ wasn't followed by a full clause in the original example; it was followed by a prepositional phrase,

Comment: @JohnLawler From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/different): Numerous commentators have condemned *different than* in spite of its use since the 17th century by many of the best-known names in English literature. It is nevertheless standard and is even recommended in many handbooks when followed by a clause, because insisting on *from* in such instances often produces clumsy or wordy formulations.

Comment: Yes, _different than I expected_ is OK, but not *_different from I expected._